# DOMParser serializeToString HTML entities issue

Tags: node.js, xml, domparser

I have some xml that I am trying to convert to xml document using DOMParser, make some changes and then convert back to xml string. But when I convert back to string using XMLSerializer, it changes `&lt;food&gt;` to `&lt;food>`, I want to keep it same.

**Code:**

```
var text = "<foodshop><food>" +
"<title>All type of &lt;food&gt; available</title>" +
"<name>Indian dish</name>" +
"<date>5th september</date>" +
"</food></foodshop>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var document = parser.parseFromString( text, 'text/xml' );

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var writetofile = serializer.serializeToString( document );
console.log(writetofile);
```

**Output:**

```
<foodshop><food><title>All type of &lt;food> available</title><name>Indian dish</name><date>5th september</date></food></foodshop>
```

Comment: The DOM doesn't distinguish between the two representation so once you have used DOMParser to parse the string the information as to whether the greater than sign was literally in the string or a an entity reference is lost and you can't expect any serializer using the DOM input to be able to restore something not saved in the DOM. And in terms of the XML syntax rules the `>` doesn't need to be escaped as `&gt;` so the serializer escapes what is necessary but doesn't do more.

Comment: I doubt you will find serializer with configurations settings/options to decide as to whether escape or not escape the `>`, at least not in the Node.js universe.

Comment: On any reasonable definition of "sameness" the output is the same as the input. That is to say, the difference is trivial, like using different line endings in a text file, and no sensible application should treat the two as different.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using another lib 'libxmljs' along with xmldom as below:

```
const x = require('libxmljs');
const { DOMParser } = require('xmldom');
const { XMLSerializer } = require('xmldom');

var text = "<foodshop><food>" +
"<title>All type of &lt;food&gt; available</title>" +
"<name>Indian dish</name>" +
"<date>5th september</date>" +
"</food></foodshop>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var document = parser.parseFromString( text, 'text/xml' );

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var writetofile = serializer.serializeToString( document );
var doc = x.parseXmlString(stringDoc)
console.log(doc.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
<foodshop><food><title>All type of &lt;food&gt; available</title><name>Indian dish</name><date>5th september</date></food></foodshop>
```